# FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException after created Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6, symfony-routing

I am new in Symfony development and I have created my first project and my first bundle with the command line `php app\console generate:bundle`.

Normally, I should be able to use this new bundle and access to the URL hello/{name}, but when I am trying to access to the URL http://localhost/mylibrary-web/web/app_dev.php/hello/test/ I am getting this error message :

`FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException in FileLoader.php line 97: Circular reference detected in "C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app/config/routing_dev.yml" ("C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app/config\routing.yml" > "C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app/config/routing_dev.yml").`

How can I resolve this issue ?

Here the routing files of my project :

**C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\config\routing_dev.yml :**

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

**C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\config\routing.yml :**

```
my_library_library:
    resource: "@MyLibraryLibraryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

**C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\src\MyLibrary\LibraryBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml :**

```
my_library_library_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MyLibraryLibraryBundle:Default:index }
```

Thank you for your help !

Edit : here the result of the command line `php app\console debug:router` :

```
C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web>php app\console debug:router
[router] Current routes
 Name                        Method Scheme Host Path
 _wdt                        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home              ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
 _profiler_search            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
 _profiler_search_bar        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
 _profiler_purge             ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
 _profiler_info              ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
 _profiler_phpinfo           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
 _profiler_search_results    ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
 _profiler                   ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
 _profiler_router            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
 _profiler_exception         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
 _profiler_exception_css     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 _configurator_home          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
 _configurator_step          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
 _configurator_final         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
 _twig_error_test            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}
 my_library_library_homepage ANY    ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}
 homepage                    ANY    ANY    ANY  /app/example
```

Edit 2 : After clearing the cache with the command line `php app\console cache:clear` I have now the following error :

```
ContextErrorException in classes.php line 6415: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\cache\dev/annotations/597877fc1359850fa8786ead82dcc8f6f491d628.cache.php
```

Comment: add output of `php app/console debug:router` here

Comment: @ghanbari : Thx for your help ! I have updated my post with the output of the requested command line !

Comment: search `routing_dev` in your project, and if exist in any routing file, delete it

Comment: @ghanbari there is no reference to `routing_dev` in my project. I clear the cache and I have now another error. I have edited my post with the details.

Comment: Can you try a hard cache clear? `rm -rf app/cache/*` or just delete all folders found inside of `app/cache`. Also check the annotations found in `@AppBundle/Controller/` to ensure there's no back-references to `routing_dev`

Comment: @ghanbari I still have the same error ` ContextErrorException in FileCacheReader.php line 102: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\cache\dev/annotations/597877fc1359850fa8786ead82dcc8f6f491d628.cache.php`

Comment: i think you have a problem in routing annotaion that define in controller, can you comment `app` route and clear cache and test again?

Comment: @ghanbari after commenting and clearing the cache I have the following error `ContextErrorException in FileCacheReader.php line 102: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\cache\dev/annotations/597877fc1359850fa8786ead82dcc8f6f491d628.cache.php`. If I try the url again, I have the following error : `ContextErrorException in classes.php line 6415: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\app\cache\dev/annotations/597877fc1359850fa8786ead82dcc8f6f491d628.cache.php`.

Comment: @ghanbari I finally found where the issue comes from. I have posted the solution into a new answer ! thx for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution... The issue comes from OPCache and the following setting : `opcache.enable_file_override=1`. After changing with `opcache.enable_file_override=0` everything works :)